# How to open http on expo react native app

Tags: android, node.js, react-native, expo

How to open http on expo react native app

I'm designing an Android app using Expo. I'm struggling with opening a localhost port on the app to create a local API route on the Android device itself. Could you please help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: We dont understand what you want. Not a word.

Comment: @blackapps I want to use the image in /sdcard to embed in the webview, so I have to open the http server in the sdcard folder. I don't know how to open an http server in expo

Comment: You do not need a http server for that. The WebView can load from file.

Comment: And why are you calling that embedding? Why not just display an image?

Comment: @blackapps My app needs to embed a webview. This webview is an html website that includes images and videos. I need to optimize performance. My app will download all images and videos from the server into /sdcard. And I'm looking for a solution to display them in the webview

Answer (score 0):

ive suferd from this befor,all u had to do is to change your sever localhost to be the same as mobile and mustt be your network localhost,for example from your pc go to your connected wifi settings and show details you will find wifi localhost that you must run ur sever and api with it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTsNl.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).